# Why does the scrapy spider file run so slowly(/not run properly) after being imported in main file?

Tags: python, scrapy, ide, web-crawler, twisted

I wrote a scrapy spider which runs normally in the python script and can scrap texts. When I imported it as a module in the main.py file and tried to run it as a module there, my IDE just keeps running and no text gets scrapped. The import was correct (I tested by writting a print function). Nothing happens after following texts. I waited for like an hour. There is no problem concerning RAM. My IDE is spyder.

Here is the messages in the console:

```
request.py:254: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
return cls(crawler)
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be? Thank you very much!

1. Here are the codes in my python file for the scrapy spider:

```
import scrapy
import urllib.parse
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

#%%
#Define Items for the pipeline
class CustomItem(Item):
    links = Field()
    text = Field()

#%%
#Define the spider
#Get the links from the website
class SecondSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "second_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["www1.wdr.de"]
    start_urls = ["https://www1.wdr.de/abisz120.html"]
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 0,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
        'ITEM_PIPELINES':{'bremenspider.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline2':300},
        'MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME2': 'human_written_texts(wdr)' # Collection for SecondSpider
    }
    
#%%        
#Get the links from the website https://www1.wdr.de/
    def parse(self, response):
        links1 = response.css('ul.list a::attr(href)').getall()
        base_link = 'https://www1.wdr.de/'
        for link in links1:
            absolute_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_link, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url, callback=self.link_parse)
            
#%%          
#Get the links from the links one layer deeper than the mentioned the website           
    def link_parse(self, response):
        links2 = response.css('div.teaser a::attr(href)').getall()
        base_link2 = 'https://www1.wdr.de/'
        for link in links2:
            absolute_url2 = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_link2, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url2, callback=self.text_parse,
                                 meta={'url': absolute_url2})
#%%
#Get the text from the links
    def text_parse(self, response):
        item = CustomItem()
        item['text'] = response.xpath('//p[@class="text small"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()').getall()
        item['links'] = response.meta['url']
        extracted_text = ' '.join(item['text']).strip()
        if extracted_text:
            yield item
            
#%%
# Define a function to run the spider from main file.

def run_wdr_spider():
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(SecondSpiderSpider)
    try:
        process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Handle KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl+C)
        process.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_wdr_spider()
```

2. Here are the codes in the main.py file:

```
#%%
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


#Module Text Crawling. 
#Texte aus der Webseite crawlen.
import wdrspider

#Call a function to crawl texts from the website of wdr.
wdrspider.run_wdr_spider()
```

Comment: crreate a [mre]

Comment: Try to run it outside the IDE, sometimes Spyder have problem to run Scrapy scripts for some reason. Please update us if it doesn't help.